# Change schema in an Impala/Hive table with a very large amount of data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, impala

We have a Hive table stored on HDFS with 800+ columns and >65 billion rows (and growing) and need to:

1. Remove a column with a complex type (small array)
2. Add a column with a complex type (small array)
3. Possibly add a handful of other columns (simple type, e.g. string or int)
4. Modify the contents of 3 columns for every row in the database (effectively read it in, make a simple change, write it back out to the same column and row that it came from). I realise this is probably a separate operation to the other three requirements above.

We could set up a new empty table with the new schema and copy the data over (using CREATE TABLE xxxxx FROM SELECT ... or INSERT INTO xxxx SELECT ...) but tests suggest it would take 1 - 3 weeks running non stop.  And it's possible we may need to make further minor similar modifications in future.

Is there an efficient, sensible alternative to copying the whole table? Would ALTER TABLE work (at least for the structural changes, items 1 - 3 above)? What are the pros and cons of either option(s)?

Table is going to be queried using Impala, in a Zeppelin-based interface.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If it's an Avro based table, you could just change the schema without actually modifying any of the data

Comment: I think using altering table structure can be a bad idea. It works, sometime it doesnt work. So i feel like create a new table in temp schema, alter table - do your thing and replace original table. This way, you always have a backup if something fails.

Comment: @KoushikRoy thanks, but I don't quite understand what you mean sorry - you say altering table is a bad idea, then say "create a new table in temp schema, alter table" - the issue is how to access all the existing data in the old table if I do create a new table? Or do you mean alter the old table somehow? Thanks again

Comment: "create a new table in temp schema, alter table" means - create new table with the data (backup) and then alter this new table. once your changes are fine, stable, working, replace original table with this new table.